# Find next specific class with Jquery and check if it has another class

Tags: javascript, jquery

With **jQuery** I want to find the next class, check if it has another class and if so, change the current item.

Example:

```
<div class="item itemA"></div> // only change this background to red
<div class="item itemA"></div>
<div class="item itemB"></div>
<div class="OtherClass"></div>
<div class="item itemA"></div>
```

I want to check if the next class "item" (which could come after some other html) also has class "itemA" and if so, change the current itemA. For example change the background to red.

In the above example only the 1st DIV would change because the next class "item" has also class "itemA". The next class "item" of the 2nd class "itemA" is "itemB" so this DIV shouldn't change.

I tried the .next() function, but it didn't work out. Mainly because there could also be other HTML between the classes. So it really needs to **find** the next "item" class, check if that "item" also has class "itemA" and alter the one before.

Any help is most welcome!

Comment: Did you try `$(this).hasClass('itemA')` ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you make it more clear?

Comment: `Mainly because there could also be other HTML between the classes` ? How will you DOM look like then ?

Comment: I think you are looking for `nextAll()`

Comment: So it's not really the next element, but any preceding sibling with the same class

Comment: .nextAll() doesn't work for me, check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BxJ4F/371/

Comment: So it's supposed to work with completely invalid HTML, and with elements that's aren't inside the same parents as well ?

Comment: Yes, it just needs to find the next class. Check out this new fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/z1b97ahp/

Comment: So like this then -> https://jsfiddle.net/z1b97ahp/2/

Comment: Thanks! Now we are moving in the right direction. Only the Index + 1 is very specific. In my altered fiddle you see which one's should be red. It needs to search for the next "item" class and if that class does not also have "itemA" in it, it should not be red, if the next "item" class has also "itemA" class, then it should be red. https://jsfiddle.net/q9mb7yhu/2/

Comment: You're not explaining this very well, this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q9mb7yhu/3/) seems to work just as expected, as all but the last `.itemA` are red

Comment: Hi Adeneo, thanks for helping! I see in your last comment that we don't understand each other perfectly. The last .itemA is not red, but what I mean is that if there are more than one itemA's after each other that the last .itemA of every array of .itemA's is not red. So if there is only one .itemA somewhere in the DOM, there is no array. In my fiddle there are 2 arrays with .itemA's. The last one of every array should not be red. If there is an array of 6, only the first 5 should be red. 

I hope this comment makes it clear :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Bob i hope you are looking for solution as below

```
var counter = 0;    
var prevElement;

//traverse all the div's
$.each($('body div'), function(){

  //if div has class "item" as first class in class list 
  if( $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0] == "item") {

    //if div has class "itemA" as second class in class list 
    if("itemA" == $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1]) {
        if(counter == 1 ) {

        //change color
        prevElement.addClass('redColor');
      } 
      counter = 1;
      prevElement = $(this);
    } 
  }
});
```

Please have a look at Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/a5y4gkzg/2/

Comment: $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0] == "item" is terribly fragile. Use $(this).hasClass('item').